# Apache redirige automaticamente a HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache2

He tenido que reinstalar Apache, Mysql y PHP por un problema que hubo en mi servidor.

Antes de esto, todo funcionaba bien, si entraba a la IP de mi servidor 192.168.X.X iba a esa IP y servía el contenido sin problema. Si entraba mediante HTTPS o HTTP, el servidor resolvía bien e iba a donde correspondía.

Pues, desde que he actualizado, entres como entres, por IP, o dominio, siempre redirige a HTTPS, provocando que no pueda ver contenido que tengo en el servidor.

¿Que ha podido pasar? ¿O que fichero debo revisar? Esta todo igual que en la configuración anterior.

Por centrar un poco el asunto, lo que necesito es saber como prohibo que cuando llegue de IP, no redirija a HTTPS

Comment: Es dificil saber que es lo que sucedio en tu sistema, pero si pudieras poner algún código se te podría ayudar. De momento, te puedo decir que eso se puede arreglar en la configuración del http.conf en la parte de directory, también en el .htaccess por carpeta, y depende de lo que estés sirviendo, lo anterior en caso de que sea html, pero si es algún framework pudiera estar redirigiendo a https.

Comment: Gracias, hice una "chapuza" con un conf y de momento parece que funciona. Pongo el código del apache2 conf?

Comment: Puedes poner el código de lo que cambiaste y el nombre del archivo, puede que le sirva a alguien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os dejo el config que solucionó mi problema

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName 192.168.x.x
        ServerAlias default
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        DirectoryIndex index.php

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Esto lo hice con la IP externa e interna, curiosamente, con HTTPS no fallaba.